# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on null using Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm using Simple HTML DOM to get elements and values from a website I'm scraping. It works great, but every 23,000 pages or so, I hit the equivalent of a 404 page not found, in which the normal html structure is not present. This results in a fatal error I want to escape without breaking the page.

Here is the full error report:

**Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\scrape\simple_html_dom.php:1113 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\scrape\scrape_detailtable.php(133): simple_html_dom->find('div[id=detailta...') #1 {main} thrown in **C:\xampp\htdocs\scrape\simple_html_dom.php** on line **1113**

Here are the lines in my script where the error occurs:

```
$doc = new simple_html_dom($record_content);
if ( ! is_null($doc->find("div[id=detailtable]")) ) // <-- this line
```

`$record_content` is the html retrieved using a cURL.

I've tried

```
if( ! isset($doc->find("div[id=detailtable]")) ) , 
if( ! is_null($doc->find("div[id=detailtable]")) ) , 
if( ! empty($doc->find("div[id=detailtable]")) ) , and , 
if( ! $doc->find("div[id=detailtable]") )  ...
```

...and the page keeps breaking. I just want to escape processing on condition of the existence of div[id=detailtable].

**update on 6/30/2016**

I got another PHP error trying different escape and "detect not null" methods (Maybe this is new with PHP 7). Eventually I tried something where PHP threw this suggestion, along with the error: (paraphrasing) "You can use null !== expression"

So now my code reads: `if ( null !== $doc->find( 'a' ) ){`

Blah! still getting "Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on null" so I guess null !== expression doesn't really work.

Comment: Can you try `if ( ! is_null($doc->find("div[id=detailtable]", 0)) )` instead of `if ( ! is_null($doc->find("div[id=detailtable]")) )` please ? Not sure about this one but worth giving a try :)

Comment: @Julqas I'll try it and report back here with my findings. It does take a few minutes to timeout, thanks.

Comment: Ok no problem, waiting for your report

Comment: It seems that `$doc` is null (as its that variable you call `find()`) on. Try debug the code and see what happens. The `new simple_html_dom(..)` call should not create a `null` object, which makes this kinda odd. Is this the exact code that bugs?

Comment: In reply to @Julqas , it seems to have worked. I had to make some minor changes, where $detailtable is no longer an array: `$e = $detailtable[0]->children()` is now `$e = $detailtable->children()`. Now, on to the next error!

Comment: @InfiniteLoop OK cool, glad it helped ! Good luck with the rest !

Comment: @Jite I don't understand it, either. Unless there really isn't a page, which may be the case. True, I get a "not found" page, but now that I think about it, that's a redirect, and not the actual page that goes with the url.

Comment: Closer check of the simple_html_dom code shows that the find method calls on the inner `$this->root->find(..)` method, its possible that the root is null and that's why it blows up. You say its a redirect, do `simple_html_dom` follow the redirect?

Comment: @Jite, it does not follow the redirect. Hence, I think that is how the root is null. It hits a page with no id="detailtable", and I get a null. So, I think your analysis is correct. I actually need to escape on null. Right now, the script is running without error.

Comment: @Jite Encountering more errors. A null root object seems to underlie my problems. Weeding them out using your observations.

Comment: The masked StackOverflow revenge downvoter strikes again!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that:

```
$doc = new simple_html_dom($record_content);
if ( $doc ) {
    if ( ($find = $doc->find("div[id=detailtable]")) ) {
        // do what you want with the $find variable
    }
    if ( ($find = $doc->find("div[id=detailtable2]")) ) {
        // do what you want with the $find variable
    }
    if ( ($find = $doc->find("div[id=detailtable3]")) ) {
        // do what you want with the $find variable
    }
}
```

Comment: With this, I already know from dissecting the html that there is only a `div[id=detailtable]`. There is never a `div[id=detailtable2]` or `div[id=detailtable3]`. When there isn't a `div[id=detailtable]` it triggers the error I was trying to get rid of. So that leaves only the inner `if`. But I've already tried `if ( ($find = $doc->find("div[id=detailtable]")) ) {` and it does not prevent the page from breaking on an error. Thanks.

Comment: @InfiniteLoop `detailtable2` and `detailtable3`.... it just for example ;-) If my response answered your question, please click on the button to select my response as the right answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @keupsonite. I appreciate it. But I'm afraid your answer doesn't really stop the error from happening. I know, I tried it.

Comment: @InfiniteLoop The error is still the same than previously?! If not, can you put the error message?